# st_startpoint(the_geom) returning empty values

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, routing, shp2pgsql

When I upload a shapefile to PostgreSQL using the QGIS tool I can create the routing topology following this [tutorial](http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/doc/src/tutorial/topology.html) without any problem.

But when I use the PostGis Shapefile Import/Export Manager or the SQL generated by the shp2pgsql.exe I can't get any values for the x1,x2,y1 and y2 fields.

```
UPDATE edge_table SET x1 = st_x(st_startpoint(the_geom)),
  y1 = st_y(st_startpoint(the_geom)),
  x2 = st_x(st_endpoint(the_geom)),
  y2 = st_y(st_endpoint(the_geom)),
cost_len  = st_length_spheroid(the_geom, 'SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.25728]'),
rcost_len = st_length_spheroid(the_geom, 'SPHEROID["WGS84",6378137,298.25728]');
```

Only cost_len and rcost_len have values after running that script.

And because of that I can't get any route at all. What am I missing?

Comment: Everything looks good.  Can you verify that X1, X2, Y1, Y2 are type double?

Comment: They all have the data type: double precision;

Comment: I have checked all the data types. On the working table I have: the_geom geography(LineString,4326). On this one I have geom geometry(MultiLineString,4326). Can that be the issue?

Comment: Ah, yeah it could be the issue.  Here's a good post for converting the MultiLineString to a LineString - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19864/how-to-convert-multilinestring-to-linestring and here is a link to the ST_LineMerge http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_LineMerge.html  Let us know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using -S on the shp2pgsql.exe to generate single geometry elemens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ST_StartPoint() only accepts LineString as input. You'll have to strip your table down from MultiLineString to LineString, either by taking only the first element up each geometry

```
ALTER TABLE foo 
  ALTER COLUMN geom 
  TYPE Geometry(LineString,4326) 
  USING ST_GeometryN(geom,1)
```

Or, more correctly, dumping the multis out, in case there are legit multis.

```
CREATE TABLE foo_single AS
   SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom::Geometry(LineString,4326) AS geom
          gid
   FROM foo;
```

Comment: Had exactely the same problem. ST_Distance() returning NULL because ST_StartPoint() was returning null as an argument. Your solution solved my problem :) thanks !

Comment: When I try to do this - I keep getting: ERROR: Geometry has Z dimension but column does not - How do I fix this?